# Disable F10 hotkey on Windows 10 (open Telegram)

Tags: windows, hotkeys

If I press the key F10 on Windows 10, Telegram desktop app starts and takes focus. This happens everywhere. How can I disable this F10 shortcut? I've searched everywhere but I don't know how to disable this. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the hardware is, this is hard to answer, but this may help.

First off I've never known Telegram to do this by default and have been using the main Windows client for years. So that means it's most likely a feature of the keyboard to remap the keys.

If it's a laptop you could look up the model and how to remap the F Keys. *(Most likely a software feature.)*

If it's a keyboard there may be software for it to do this, for example, Logitech has a lot of software for its keyboards to remap keys or program keys for gamers.

The other option would be for some software to be installed like 'AutoHotKey' and that type of software is being used to remap the keyboard. Windows also has a feature to 'remap' keys with their powertoys software.

But you should share the information of the Telegram client you are using and what hardware is being used, that will aid in finding the issue here.

Comment: I'm using a desktop pc. No laptop. The keyboard is a mechanical keyboard without any special software. I'm using 'AutoHotKey' but this behavior also occurs when I shut down 'AutoHotKey'. I'm using the official last version of Telegram desktop for Windows.

Comment: can you go deep on "Windows also has a feature to 'remap' keys with their powertoys software."? What software?

Comment: You can read more about Microsoft's Remap PowerToys [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager)